# Migrating Anaconda root environment to new machine

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I recently got a new OS X computer, coming from an earlier version of OS X, and would like to clone my root environment onto my new machine. I have exported my root environment on my old machine using

`conda env export --name root -f root.yml`

Now I would like to "clone" this root environment on my new machine, but can't use

`conda env create --name root -f root.yml`

because I get the error `CondaValueError: Value error: prefix already exists: /Users/user/anaconda`. This makes sense; it doesn't want to overwrite the root environment in `/Users/user/anaconda`, but is there a way to tell anaconda to download and install all the packages in `root.yml` into the root environment?

Answer (score 3):

*This might work*. I've used this to copy my conda root environment from my OS X computer to our linux servers on which conda was already installed.
On your old OS X machine:

```
$conda list -e > root-spec.txt
```

Then edit root-spec.txt and remove the two lines which look like:

```
conda=4.1.12=py27_0
conda-env=2.5.2=py27_0
```

(since conda is already installed)

copy root-spec.txt to your new machine and try:

```
conda install --file root-spec.txt
```

Comment: It gets it on the way there, but there are lot of old dependencies that screw things up. For those that do this, I would recommend doing a `conda clean` before doing this, and also doesn't include any of the `pip` installs. What would be nice from Anaconda would be something like Homebrew's `brew leaves` which only shows packages which are not a dependent on any other package, therefore requiring the installation of all other dependents on their install.